# Javascript debugging plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, javascript

I'm new to Java and I'm doing a project with Ext JS and Java. I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Build id: 20100218-1602). Can anyone suggest any Javascript debugging plugin for this build? Links appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Also IE developer tools are pretty good. In IE8 just hit F12 also.

Since javascript is the browser technology you should debug it in browser to see the real-world behavior.

Answer (score 1):

FireBug is almost certainly the best way to debug your javascript to test in a browser :) although it's worth noting some bugs manifest themselves in FFX and not IE (also vice versa), so check in both!

Comment: Also Chrome is gaining some ground and it has some developer tools via right click -> inspect element or so.  Opera is another good one to check.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox. I'd say it's the best JavaScript debugger and overall web development tool out there today. You just install it and hit F12 and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

- [Eclipse Webtools Platform JavaScript Development Toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/) - install via the Install New Software menu in Eclipse
- [Aptana Studio 2 Eclipse Plugin](http://aptana.com/products/studio2/download) - there is an install/update link to use in Eclipse

Comment: hi Dean Burge,
can u provide help on how to install the "Eclipse Webtools Platform JavaScript Development Toolkit " plugin in eclipse...i can't able to proceed after -->New Software menu...

Comment: Help menu -> Install New Software -> in the Work with menu select "All Available Sites" -> expand the Programming Languages section below and select JavaScript Developer Tools then click next. Recently I also came across this which may be of use: http://code.google.com/p/jsdt/

Comment: hi Dean Burge,(thanks for ur reply man)
i follwed ur steps up to "Developer Tools then click next" ..eclipse installed the plugin successfully and alert me to restart the eclipse, i restarted it even though i cant able to insert or add the break point in the js file.. and wht abt this"code.google.com/p/jsdt" link ..i downloaded it but i cant able to install in eclipse...

Comment: Better idea: download the web developer edition of eclipse that has WTP in it.